# Mobile iframe youtube viewing trying to download and not show video

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, iframe, youtube

I have the following code working for desktop but not mobile. The code displays an image and if that image is clicked it will then replace it with an iframe holding the youtube video assigned to it..

```
<img src="/image/background/ph_shop.jpg" alt="Shop Directions" class="video-placeholder img-force shadow-box pointer" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/v/m8qcEilvdMQ&rel=0&autoplay=1" />
<script>
     $(".video-placeholder").click(function(){
          var video = \'<iframe frameborder="0" class="width-100 shadow-box" height="400" src="\'+ $(this).attr(\'data-video\') +\'" allowfullscreen></iframe>\';
          $(this).replaceWith(video);
     });
</script>
```

When I try to click the image in mobile it removes the image but doesn't load anything in it's place and then it tries to download a file that cannot be opened called "m8qcEilvdMQ&rel=0&autoplay=1"

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and solved it!

The solution is to change your YouTube Video URL.

Replace the `/v/` in your url with `/embed/`.

For example, replace your URL `https://www.youtube.com/v/m8qcEilvdMQ&rel=0&autoplay=1` with `https://www.youtube.com/embed/m8qcEilvdMQ&rel=0&autoplay=1`

I don't know why the "`v`" URL starts a download, I think it is because it returns the header with content-type `application/x-shockwave-flash`, and the `embed` URL returns a content-type `text/html`.

Comment: Thank you, you saved me lot of time :)